# Showing that a if a real matrix $A$ satisfies $A^t=A^3$, then $A^2$ is diagonalizable over the reals

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, diagonalization

I tried proving that if $A$ is a real square matrix with $A^t=A^3$, then $A^2$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

Since $A^t=A^3, A$ if considered as a complex matrix, commutes with its adjoint. So $A=U^*DU$ for a diagonal matrix $D$ containing the eigenvalues of $A$. Then $A^2=U^*D^2U$ and $D^2$ has entries $\lambda^2$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. Now note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ with eigenvector $v$, $\bar\lambda$ is one of $A^*=A^t$ with the same eigenvector, but then $\bar\lambda$ must also be an eigenvalue of $A^3$ with same vector. So we have $A^3v=\bar\lambda v=\lambda^3 v$. So $\bar\lambda=\lambda^3$ and so $\lambda\bar\lambda=|\lambda|^2=\lambda^4$. Hence $\lambda^4$ is the square of a real number and thus $\lambda^2$ is real for all $\lambda$. So eigenvalues of $A^2$ are real and the matrix $D^2$ above is a real matrix. Consequently, $U$ is actually orthogonal when we write $A^2=U^*D^2U$ and so $A^2$ is indeed diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

My question is, is the above solution correct, or is there any flaws in it?

Comment: How do you get from $\bar \lambda = \lambda^3$ to $\lambda^2 = |\lambda|$?

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054148/normal-operator-over-real-inner-product-space/2054256#2054256)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is mostly correct.  You should take care to fix the statement

> So $\bar\lambda=\lambda^3$ and so $\lambda^2=|\lambda|$ is real for all $\lambda$.

I would say $(\lambda^2)^2 = |\lambda|^2$, which means that $\lambda^2$ is real.  Also, you should clarify how you deduce

> So eigenvalues of $A^2$ are real and the matrix $D^2$ above is a real matrix. **Consequently**, $U$ is actually orthogonal when we write $A^2=U^*D^2U$ and so $A^2$ is indeed diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo about $|\lambda|^2$, corrected that. About the second point, $U$ is actually a base change matrix changing from standard basis to a basis where the matrix is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues, that is the eigenbasis. Since both $A^2$ and $D^2$ are real matrices, the base change matrix has to be real.

Comment: Now is the solution complete?

Comment: You seem to be saying something like "if $P$ and $Q$ are real matrices and $P$ is unitarily similar to $Q$, then $P$ is also orthogonally similar to $Q$".  I believe that this is the case, but it's by no means a trivial statement.  "The base change matrix has to be real" is not, taken at face value, a valid statement.

Comment: You may also consider ending your proof with "$A^2$ is normal with real eigenvalues, so it is Hermitian.  It has real entries, so it's symmetric.  Since $A^2$ is a real symmetric matrix, it is diagonalizable over the reals".  This assumes that you've discussed the spectral theorem over real vector spaces.

Comment: Yes, I think that's also possible. But honestly I don't get the problem with the above argument. With $A^2=U^*D^2U$ and the entries in $D^2$ being the eigenvalues of $A^2$, don't we get that $U$ is the basechange matrix from the standard basis to the eigenbasis? If so, since both these bases have real vectors (since $A$ is real and the eigenvectors for the real eigenvalues are real too), how can the base change matrix not be real? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are many possible $U$ that do the job. Note that if an orthogonal $U$ works, then so does the unitary matrix $iU$.

Comment: "which means that $\lambda$ is real". Do you mean $\lambda^2$ here? Otherwise $\lambda=i$ is not real.

Comment: Yes, of course. But that is because if $v_i$ are the eigenbasis vectors, so are $iv_i$. What I'm saying that there is a choice of the eigenbasis vectors to be all real as the eigenvalues are real and then we get the orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. That orthogonal matrix may not be the $U$ we started with. Is that the point?

Comment: @adrija exactly.